# Can Massive cooperate with MySql?

Tags: c#, orm, massive

I would like to use [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) with MySql and I see there are SQL (default), PostgreSQL, Oracle, and Sqllite providers for Massive. Is there a provider for MySql or does one of the other providers work for MySql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Massive is SQL Server only and I work with MySQL, I’ve forked it to add MySQL support.

You can find the repository over at [GitHub](https://github.com/alexandernyquist/massive-mysql). There is also a NuGet package available, named Massive.MySQL which has MySQL.Data as a dependency. This means that you only need to do the following to get a working data access wrapper:

```
Install-Package Massive.MySQL
```

For more details [check this out](http://nyqui.st/massive-data-access-for-mysql)

Comment: Massive now supports Postgres, Oracle, and SQLite (as indicated in the post). See the [github repo](https://github.com/robconery/massive). I'm not sure whether direct MySQL support is coming.